# Spring Data JPA - Having entity keep track of how many entities reference him

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Ok, so basically i have two entites, ChatSession and ApplicatonUser. The chat represents a chat room, and always has 2 people in it. To represent the chat and these two people, i used this entity:

```
public class ChatSession {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    ApplicationUser firstUser;

    @ManyToOne
    ApplicationUser secondUser;
}
```

And my ApplicationUser entity has nothing relevant:

```
public class ApplicationUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

And this is working well for me. But when i want to find a chat for a certain user, i dont want to look through all the chats to find it. Is there anyway i can make ApplicationUser keep track of all of the chats he is apart of, so when i am looking for a chat a user is apart of, i only have to look through the chats he is apart of. How would i map this using Spring data? I know i can have a:

```
@OneToMany
List<ChatSessions> listOfChatSessions
```

But that does not seem to work for me here, and i think that searches through all the chats anyway.

Comment: I think you have a problem with the way are modelling the user/chat relationship. A chat requires more than one user. A user can have more than one chat. What you really have is a many to many relationship. When you get the relationship correctly modeled each user will have a collection of chats, which is what you really want.

Comment: @TheHeadRush yeah i was kinda considering a ManyToMany, but since it was only two users in the chat i wanted to try something diffrent. However the case, is there anyway i can have the entity refrenced by ManyToOne relationships (like ApplicatinoUser in this case), keep track of the entities he is being refrenced from?

Comment: If all you want is to have a `User` entity know which chats it participates in, add a `@ManyToOne Collection<ChatSession>` to the user. But what will you do when your users ask for a group chat feature?

Comment: Yeah i will probably move to a ManyToMany, anyway the ManyToOne Collection<ChatSession> is not working for me, i though it would automaticly add it to the users, but the value is null for users i add to a chatsession.

Comment: I seem to have led you down the wrong path. To make the relationship bidirectional you need to use the inverse annotation, so i should have said use `@OneToMany` and `@JoinColumn`. I apologize.